# attachInterupt(), for RISING and FALLING separately in arduino

Tags: arduino, interrupt, arduino-uno, interrupt-handling

I am using Arduino uno for reading an encoder (optical), can I attach interrupt for RISING and FALLING separately instead of using CHANGE?

Comment: I tried but, its not reading in the expected fashion, resolution became x2 instead of x4. Can anyone explain this? I am new to arduino.

Comment: Post some code and results expected vs obtained

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the last interrupt attached to the pin will only be active.